# RequireJS Optimizer hard include

Tags: javascript, requirejs, r.js, requirejs-optimizer

I have a large-scale client-side project which I would like to bundle into 2 bundles instead of 1.

This is my dependency tree:

[image: module's dependency tree]

The desired output would be to have these bundles:

1. `main` that includes `b`
2. `x` that includes just `a` (as `b` is already included in the first bundle and I do not want users to download more than once a piece of code).

Here's my optimizer configuration:

```
({
  appDir: 'www',
  baseUrl: 'js/',
  mainConfigFile: 'www/js/require.config.js',
  dir: 'www-release',
  modules: [
    {
      name: 'main',
      exclude: ['x']
    },
    {
      name: 'x',
      exclude: ['main']
    }
  ],
  optimize: 'none',
  removeCombined: true
})
```

I do want to exclude from `main` the whole dependency tree of `x`, yet still include modules that I explicitly require, such as `a`.

I know that:

1. `include` — explicitly include module that are not required directly and its whole dependency tree.
2. `exclude` — excluding a module is actually excluding its whole dependency tree, overriding `include` incase of a conflict.
3. `excludeShallow` — includes the module’s dependency tree, **not** including the module itself.

Having that, I do not see a clear way to accomplish what I want, can you help?

Comment: Is something like this valid? `{
      name: 'x',
      exclude: ['main', 'b']
    }` ? Have you considered using webpack by the way?

Comment: This won't work, b will be missing in both bundles this way. Regarding webpack - I have but for now I'm stuck with requirejs, I do not know what is the cost of switching to webpack. I have the feeling it's not going to be quick.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use requier.js bundling functionality like this.

**In your require.config.js file**

Need write bundles settings

```
bundles: {
    x: ['files for x bundle'],
    b: ['files for b bundle']
}
```

after this need change build file.

**Optimizer configuration file**

```
({
     appDir: 'www',
     baseUrl: 'js/',
    // mainConfigFile: 'www/js/require.config.js',// not need here
     dir: 'www-release',
     modules: [
        {
            name: 'main',
            create: true, // this will create www-release/main.js file(main bundle)
            include: ['main'],
            exclude: ['x']
        },
        {
            name: 'b',
            create: true,
            include: ['files for b bundle'],
            exclude: ['main']
        },
        {
            name: 'x',
            create: true,
            include: ['files for x bundle']
            exclude: ['main']
        }
   ],
   optimize: 'none',
   removeCombined: true
   paths: {
       //put paths object from requierjs.confige file 
   }
});
```

Comment: The OP wants to create two bundles, not 3.

Comment: in that case need just add 2 modules and 2 bundles